# Validating radio buttons in php not working

Tags: php, html

I am trying to validate radio buttons using PHP. However, even if one of the options is selected, I still get an error message stating that neither one of the radio buttons have been selected which is "Please select your qualification. This is my html code:

```
<p>Qualification: </p> 
<p><label for="underGrad">Undergraduate</label>
<input type="radio" id="underGrad" name="qualification" value="underGrad">
</p>
<p><label for="postGrad">Postgraduate</label>
<input type="radio" id="postGrad" name="qualification" value="postGrad">
</p>
```

My PHP validation code:

```
if (!isset($_POST["qualification"])) {
        header("location:register.php");
        exit(); 
    }
    else{
        $qualification=$_POST["qualification"];  
        $qualification=sanitise_input($qualification);
        if (($qualification!=="underGrad") or (qualification!=="postGrad")) {
            $err_msg .="<p>Please select your qualification.</p>";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your logic is failing, if you look at

```
if (($qualification!=="underGrad") or (qualification!=="postGrad")) {
```

it's saying if the qualification is not undergrad or postgrad, as it can't be both, the or will always say one doesn't match.

You could either use `and` to say if it's not either...

```
if (($qualification!=="underGrad") and (qualification!=="postGrad")) {
```

or you could just say if it's empty (so it must contain something )

```
if ( empty($qualification) ) {
```

this last one will also allow you to add more options without having to update the condition.

Comment: I changed the logic as suggested but now I am not getting an error even if neither of the options are selected

Comment: Try checking what the value is `echo '#'.$qualification.'#';` to see what is in the field.

Answer (score 0):

You have use wrong login (or) i think you should use &&. use following code

```
if (!isset($_POST["qualification"])) {
        header("location:register.php");
        exit(); 
    }
    else{
        $qualification=$_POST["qualification"];  
        $qualification=sanitise_input($reference);
        if (($qualification!=="underGrad") and (qualification!=="postGrad")) {
            $err_msg .="<p>Please select your qualification.</p>";
        }
    }
```